# I have a docker image. How can I convert it to a vmdk disk format that can be started with vmware

Tags: linux

A spring middleware is deployed in the docker image. I want to make the docker image into vmdk format and then use vmware for subsequent research.

Comment: I have VMware Workstation V17 here.  I think you would have to use the VMware Import function and see if that works.  You may need to install Docker fresh.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50394371/how-to-convert-vm-image-to-dockerfile) might be helpful

Comment: There is no kernel and system boot inside the docker image. Importing the image directly into vmware will cause no boot.

Answer (score 0):

I have VMware V17 here and did some research.

I came to the the same conclusion that there is no kernel or boot.

So you will need to install an operating system in VMware that will allow you to install Docker.

I am sure that is the only option open to you.

Comment: The author wants to convert their Docker container to a VMWare virtual HDD that they can boot.  You have the correct idea, the Docker container, does not contain a kernel or boot partition.

Comment: Yes, I want to do that.

Comment: I export the docker image and hang it on the ext3 format disk, and then try to use the extlinux tool to install the kernel and boot for the disk, but the prompt warns that the installation location is a device. Is there any other way to install it?

Comment: Some of this is guess work, but I imagine you will need to install a supporting OS, then move the extracted content from the docket into that OS. You will then need to "connect" and start it all. I.e. Databases will needed added to a database instance, and services etc will need started.  I expect this will be a very manual exercise.   Any chance you could just use a standard non-docker installation of what you are trying to test. That may be easier??

Comment: Is there any other way to install it?  ........   You need to install a supporting OS as I noted in my answer